# Turkey's secret underground city

Tags: turkey, identify-this, where-on-earth

On Feb 14, 2017 the BBC released a video on their website entitled [Turkey's secret underground city](http://www.bbc.com/travel/story/20170209-turkeys-secret-underground-city) but they don't actually mention the name of the city. They video concludes by saying "*authorities hope to open it to the public in 2018*".

My question is where might I find more information out about this underground city?

[Derinkuyu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derinkuyu_underground_city) sounds like a possible candidate but the Google satellite imagry doesn't seem to match up with what's being shown in the BBC video.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had a search on Turkish sources. This underground city doesn't seem to have an official name yet, but it is certainly different from Derinkuyu Underground City.

[image: nevsehir underground city]

According to [NTV](https://www.ntv.com.tr/galeri/sanat/dunyanin-en-buyuk-yeralti-sehri-nevsehirde-hizmete-aciliyor,Wyu_WoF9gkmDeISE-6qGZg), it is next to [Nevsehir Castle](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Nev%C5%9Fehir+Castle/@38.6196482,34.7103293,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x152a6e7208430b73:0xb56db4269bbadf39!8m2!3d38.619644!4d34.712518) (Turkish: Nevşehir Kalesi). The castle can be seen on the image (from NTV) as well. It is in the central town of Nevsehir Province and 31.6 km from Derinkuyu Underground City. By the way, Derinkuyu is also a district of Nevsehir Province.

[image: nevsehir-derinkuyu]

Comment: If you mouse over the dark background on the BBC web page you get an alt text saying "Turkey, Nevsehir, underground (Credit: Credit: Anadolu Agency/Getty)".

Answer (score 8):

Derinkuyu was discovered a while ago and opened to the public in 1969. A quick search turned up a [National Geographic article](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2015/03/150325-underground-city-cappadocia-turkey-archaeology/) which names the above-ground city in Cappadocia as Nevşehir.